# Relacionamento entre quatro tabelas

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Alterei o diagrama de um banco que eu tinha e agora preciso de uma ajuda pra efetuar um select de forma correta.

Tenho quatro tabelas, onde:
1 - Corpo Docente
2 - Treinamentos
3 - Coordenador
4 - Instrutor

Do corpo docente, qualquer dado pode ser instrutor ou coordenador.
Do treinamento, qualquer dado recebe n coordenadores e n instrutores.

Preciso fazer um select com join de modo que exiba o(s) coordenador(es) e instrutor(es) do treinamento.

[image: Tabelas relacionadas]

```
SELECT * FROM treinamentos t
LEFT JOIN treinamentos_has_coordenador tc ON t.idtreinamentos = tc.treinamentos_idtreinamentos
RIGHT JOIN treinamentos_has_instrutor ti ON t.idtreinamentos = ti.treinamentos_idtreinamentos
JOIN corpo_docente ON (idcorpo_docente = tc.coordenador_idcorpo_docente
OR idcorpo_docente = ti.instrutor_idcorpo_docente)
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que algo assim te resolve:

```
SELECT t.titulo, cord.nome as nome_coordenador, inst.nome as nome_instrutor
   FROM treinamentos t
    LEFT JOIN treinamentos_has_coordenador tc ON t.idtreinamentos = tc.treinamentos_idtreinamentos
    LEFT JOIN corpo_docente cord on cord.idcorpo_docente = tc.coordenador_idcorpo_docente
    LEFT JOIN treinamentos_has_instrutor ti ON t.idtreinamentos = ti.treinamentos_idtreinamentos
    LEFT JOIN corpo_docente inst ON inst.idcorpo_docente  = ti.instrutor_idcorpo_docente
```

Abs.